# How do I see files and directories in an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am connected to my ec2 instance and I am trying to see all of the files/directories on the instance. I am using `ls` but nothing is showing up.

How do I see files and directories in an EC2 instance?

Comment: this means that you have nothing in your home folder, except hidden files/folder. to show those, `ls -la`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to copy directories from my local machine to the instance? Do I copy them before or after logging into the instance? I am using `scp -i "[pem]" -r /[directory] ec2-user@ec2-[ip].amazonaws.com` before logging into the instance and it is not working.

Comment: An Amazon EC2 instance is a computer just like another other computer. It runs the same operating system (Windows or Linux). The fact that it is an Amazon EC2 instance does not impact how the computer and operating system operates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To show all files in your home folder, use `ls -la`.

To copy files form local workstation to instance, your `scp` command is **missing a destination folder**. The following should overcome the issue (note `:.` at the end):

```
scp -i "[pem]" -r /[directory] ec2-user@ec2-[ip].amazonaws.com:.
```

Also since you have `/[directory]` this will look for the `[directory]` in the root of your filesystem, not your current working directory. For that, you can use (note `.`):

```
scp -i "[pem]" -r ./[directory] ec2-user@ec2-[ip].amazonaws.com:.
```